# How to forward accelerator key presses in main window to a detached dock widget?

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a dock widget with multiple widgets like checkboxes etc. which use accelerators. When the dock is attached to the main window, I can use the accelerator keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle the checkboxes (see the test code below).

But when the dock is detached and the main window is active, the accelerators don't work because they are handled by the dock window, while the key presses get to the main window.

I'd like to somehow pass the key presses that the main window gets to the dock window (without switching the active window of course!), so that the accelerator keys were handled as if the dock were the active window. How can I achieve this?

Here's the test code:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QLabel>

class Tools : public QDockWidget
{
    QCheckBox* check1;
    QCheckBox* check2;
    QLabel* label;
public:
    Tools(QLabel* label)
        : check1(new QCheckBox("Check &one"))
        , check2(new QCheckBox("Check &two"))
        , label(label)
    {
        const auto widget = new QWidget;
        setWidget(widget);
        const auto layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        widget->setLayout(layout);
        layout->addWidget(check1);
        layout->addWidget(check2);
        connect(check1, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, [label](const int state)
         { label->setText(QString("Check 1 %1checked").arg(state ? "" : "un")); });
        connect(check2, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, [label](const int state)
         { label->setText(QString("Check 2 %1checked").arg(state ? "" : "un")); });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    const auto label = new QLabel("started");
    window.setCentralWidget(label);
    const auto tools = new Tools(label);
    window.addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, tools);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your accelerator code written?

You can use a `QAction` with a shortcut. If you add the action to the MainWindow, the shortcut context is window shortcut (the default, see the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#shortcutContext-prop)) but if you add the action to your dock widget, you must set the context to application shortcut.

Comment: I don't have any special code, see the example given in the OP. Just adding `&` before the accelerator key in the checkbox label. My point is to avoid duplication of definitions, and addition of a `QAction` would be exactly such a duplication.

Comment: I think you cannot change the context of a mnemonic shortcut. You need to remove the ampersand key and add yourself a shortcut or an action with the application context. See the code of [QAbstractButton](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp.html).